# Minimal polynomial is lcm of minimal polynomials of invariant subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

**Question.**
I am working on Hoffman and Kunze, page 219, question 4c, they ask: Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Suppose $V = W_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_k$ where each $W_i$ is invariant under $T$. Let $T_i$ be the induced restriction operator on $W_i$. Prove that the minimal polynomial for $T$ is the least common multiple of the minimal polynomials for $T_1, \dots, T_k$.

**Solution.** To solve this, I let $m_i$ be the minimal polynomial of $T_i$ and $m$ the minimal polynomial of $T$. My strategy is to prove that:

$p$ is an annihilating polynomial of $T$ if and only if $p$ is a common multiple of the $m_i$. (1)

Then, assuming (1) is true, $m$ divides every annihilating polynomial $p$, so $m$ is the least common multiple of the $m_i$. I think I have proved (1), and I won't bother with the details for now because my question is: Is (1) a true statement? Or have I "proved" something that isn't true at all?

**Follow Up.** I'm asking, in part, because a recent question on a qualifying exam at my school asked almost exactly this, except they say that $V = W_1 + \cdots + W_k$. So, assuming (1) is true, is (1) also true under the weaker assumption that $V = W_1 + \cdots + W_k$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, (1) is a true statement. Perhaps the clearer version is "$p$ is an annihilating polynomial of $T$ if and only if it is an annihilating polynomial for each $T_i$".

Comment: For the case of $+$ (where there is potential overlap between the $W_j$), all we can say is that the minimal polynomial of $T$ **divides** the lcm of the minimal polynomials.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for your response. If I may, I'd like to follow up for confirmation. A question on my recent qual read, "Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$ over field $F$, and suppose $W_1, \dots, W_k$ are $T$-invariant subspaces of $V$ such that $V = W_1 + \cdots + W_k$. Let $m_i(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $T|_{W_i}$ for each $1 \leq i \leq k$. Prove that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is lcm$(m_1, \dots, m_k)$." What you're saying is that the thing we were meant to prove does not actually follow from the given assumptions?

Comment: That's what I thought, but on second thought the counterexample that I originally had in mind doesn't work

Comment: Indeed, it isn't too hard to see that my version of statement (1) applies to the situation with overlapping subspaces as well

Comment: Ah Ok. I'll keep pondering! Thanks for the affirmation that I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must of course in all cases assume the subspaces $W_i$ to be invariant under$~T$, so that restriction of $T$ to $W_i$ makes sense as a linear operator in $W_i$, and has a minimal polynomial in the first place. Now clearly any polynomial annihilating $T$ will annihilate any restriction of$~T$ as well. On the other hand, a polynomial $P$ annihilating $T|_{W_i}$ means that $W_i\subseteq\ker(P[T])$, and if this holds for every$~i$, then $\ker(P[T])$ contains the sum of the subspaces$~W_i$. But if that sum equals the whole space$~V$, then this means that $P[T]=0$ and $P$ is an annihilating polynomial of$~T$. So indeed, if $V=W_1+\cdots+W_k$ then $P$ is an annihilating polynomial of$~T$ if and only if it is a multiple of the minimal polynomial for every restriction of $T$ to a $W_i$, and the minimal degree (monic) such polynomial is by definition the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of those minimal polynomials. No direct sum required.